# Using the random function in Python for Evil Hangman

Tags: python-3.x, random

What I am trying to do is alter my original hangman game into what is called evil hangman. In order to do this, I need to first generate a random length of a word and pull out all words of that length from the original list.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
def setUp():
"""shows instructions, reads file,and returns a list of words from the english dictionary"""
try:
    print(60*'*' +'''\n\t\tWelcome to Hangman!\n\t
I have selected a word from an english dictionary. \n\t
I will first show you the length of the secret word\n\t
as a series of dashes.\n\t
Your task is to guess the secret word one letter at a time.\n\t
If you guess a correct letter I will show you the guessed\n\t
letter(s) in the correct position.\n
You can only make 8 wrong guesses before you are hanged\n
\t\tGood luck\n''' + 60*'*')
    infile=open('dictionary.txt')
    l=infile.readlines()# list of words from which to choose
    infile.close()
    cleanList = []
    for word in l:
        cleanList.append(l[:-1])
    return(cleanList)
except IOError:
    print('There was a problem loading the dictionary file as is.')

def sort_dict_words_by_length(words):
    """Given a list containing words of different length, 
    sort those words based on their length."""

    d = defaultdict(list)
    for word in words:
        d[len(word)].append(word)
    return d

def pick_random_length_from_dictionary(diction):
    max_len, min_len = ( f(diction.keys()) for f in (max, min) )
    length = random.randint(min_len, max_len)
    return diction[length]

def playRound(w,g):
    """ It allows user to guess one letter. If right,places letter in correct positions in    current guess string g, and shows current guess to user
if not, increments w, number of wrongs. Returns current number of wrongs and current guess string"""
    print('You have ' + str(8 - w) + ' possible wrong guesses left.\n')
    newLetter = input('Please guess a letter of the secret word:\n')
    glist = list(g)#need to make changes to current guess string so need a mutable version of it
    if newLetter in secretWord:
        for j in range (0,len(secretWord)):
            if secretWord[j]==newLetter:
               glist[j] = newLetter
        g = ''.join(glist)#reassemble the guess as a string
        print('Your letter is indeed present in the secret word: ' +  ' '.join(g)+'\n')
    else:
        w += 1
        print('Sorry, there are no ' + newLetter + ' in the secret word. Try again.\n')
    return(w,g)

def endRound(wr, w,l):
"""determines whether user guessed secret word, in which case updates s[0], or failed after w=8 attempts, in s\which case it updates s[1]"""
    if wr == 8:
            l += 1
            print('Sorry, you have lost this game.\n\nThe secret word was '+secretWord +'\n')#minor violation of encapsulation
    else:
        w +=1
        print(15*'*' + 'You got it!' + 15*'*')
    return(w,l)

def askIfMore():
    """ask user if s/he wants to play another round of the game"""
    while True:
        more = input('Would you like to play another round?(y/n)')
        if more[0].upper() == 'Y' or more[0].upper()=='N':
            return more[0].upper()
        else:
            continue

def printStats(w,l):
    """prints final statistics"""
    wGames='games'
    lGames = 'games'
    if w == 1:
        wGames = 'game'
    if l ==1:
        lGames = 'game'
    print('''Thank you for playing with us!\nYou have won {} {} and lost {} {}.\nGoodbye.'''.format(w,wGames,l,lGames))

try:

    import random
    from collections import defaultdict
    words=setUp()#list of words from which to choose
    won, lost = 0,0 #accumulators for games won, and lost
    while True:
        wrongs=0 # accumulator for wrong guesses
        secretWord = random.choice(words)[:#eliminates '\n' at the end of each line
        print(secretWord) #for testing purposes
        guess= len(secretWord)*'_'
        print('Secret Word:' + ' '.join(guess))
        while wrongs < 8 and guess != secretWord:
            wrongs, guess = playRound(wrongs, guess)
        won, lost = endRound(wrongs,won,lost)
        if askIfMore()== 'N':
            break
    printStats(won, lost)
except:
    quit()
```

What I would like to do is generate a random number with the lower bound being the shortest length word and the upper bound being the highest length word, and then use that random number to create a new container with words of only that length, and finally returning that container to be used by the game further. I tried using min and max, but it seems to only return the first and last item of the list instead of showing the word with the most characters. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 'dictionary.txt' has a single word on each line, you could use the following, which is speed efficient, because it'll only go over the list once. But it'll consume the memory of your original list again.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import random

def sort_dict_words_by_length(words):
    """Given a list containing words of different length, 
    sort those words based on their length."""

    d = defaultdict(list)
    for word in words:
        d[len(word)].append(word)
    return d

def pick_random_length_from_dictionary(diction):
    max_len, min_len = ( f(diction.keys()) for f in (max, min) )
    length = random.randint(min_len, max_len)
    return diction[length]
```

You would then pass the output from your `setUp` to `sort_dict_words_by_length` and that output to `pick_random_length_from_dictionary`.

If you are memory-limited, then you should first go over all words in the wordlist, keeping track of the minimal and maximal length of those words and then reiterate over that wordlist, appending only those words of the desired length. What you need for that is mentioned in the code above and just requires some code reshuffling. I'll leave that up to you as an exercise.

Comment: I added my full code for context and to make sure I am implementing this correctly. So in order to use your suggestions I would pass cleanList which is returned from the setUp() function to the sort dict function? Actually, the results of the setUp function is stored in the variable 'words' so I would pass that to the sort function?

Comment: Nevermind, I played around with it and figured it out. Thank you for the help.